# ¿Porque me saltan tantos errores en consola python por la librería Yaml?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este fichero de login.txt

```
# Aqui tenemos las 7 variables para poder trabajar en Pruebas_Arrays.py
# -["dirServer", "puerto", "usuario","passwd","rutaServer","rutaDescarga","patron"]

# Datos 
- ['10.0.0.3','22' ,'****'                  ,'********'    ,'/usr/amat'    ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'yyyymmdd']
- ['10.0.0.4','21' ,'******r'         ,'*******'   ,'/'            ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'\"[\w_]\" + fecha + \"\d+_\d+.bak\"']
- ['10.0.0.5','21' ,'********'         ,'********'  ,'/'            ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'.qvw']
```

Leo el fichero entero desde un fichero Python y hago las operaciones y hasta ahi todo esta bien.
Ahora necesito incluir una variable en ese fichero login.txt que es

```
# formato obligatorio de Yaml para la creacion de variables
fecha: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

el fichero login.txt quedaria asi:

```
# Aqui tenemos las 7 variables para poder trabajar en Pruebas_Arrays.py
# -["dirServer", "puerto", "usuario","passwd","rutaServer","rutaDescarga","patron"]

# Datos 
- ['10.0.0.3','22' ,'****'                  ,'********'    ,'/usr/amat'    ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'yyyymmdd']
- ['10.0.0.4','21' ,'*******'         ,'*******'   ,'/'            ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'\"[\w_]\" + fecha + \"\d+_\d+.bak\"']
- ['10.0.0.5','21' ,'********'         ,'********'  ,'/'            ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'.qvw']

# formato obligatorio de Yaml para la creacion de variables
fecha: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

¿Porque me da esta serie de errores?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pruebas_Arrays.py", line 141, in <module>
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 94, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\constructor.py", line 35, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\composer.py", line 39, in get_single_node
    if not self.check_event(StreamEndEvent):
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 174, in parse_document_start
    self.peek_token().start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "login.txt", line 14, column 1
```

Comment: Si el yaml que muestras es tal cual, tiene pinta de ser inválido. Puede probarlo con algún validador externo como: https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

Comment: He probado el verificador que me pusiste y dice que la sintaxis es correcta pero me sigue dando lo mismos errores
- ['10.0.0.3','22' ,'Root'                 ,'Miu6nb87ahJAh'    ,'/usr/amat'    ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'yyyymmdd']
- ['10.0.0.4','21' ,'Administrador'         ,'Buyrb76FJ75gas'   ,'/'            ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'"[\w_]" + fecha + "\d+_\d+.bak"']
- ['10.0.0.5','21' ,'Administrador'         ,'s54gFGn6JAJ76s6'  ,'/'            ,'C:\Users\becario2adm'        ,'.qvw']

- fecha: [datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
 me sigue dando los mismos fallos

Comment: Olvidalo, la edición de @abulafia corrigió los problemas de validez del archivo así que el problema debiera estar en otro lugar

Comment: El yaml primero es válido, pero el segundo ya no por la línea final añadida `fecha: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. Yaml no es python. No puedes definir "variables" en él, y menos hacer uso de módulos como `datetime`. Eso deberías hacerlo desde python, una vez leido el yaml. Lo difícil es marcar de algun modo el yaml para indicar donde debe ir la fecha a cambiar. Podrías usar `str.format()` y tener en el yaml una cadena que lleve `{}` donde habría de ir la fecha.